# Solve integral $\iint_{x^2+y^2<\sqrt{x}}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}dxdy$

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, lebesgue-integral

Solve integral $$\iint_{x^2+y^2<\sqrt{x}}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}dxdy$$

I was thinking about substitution $(x,y)\mapsto(t^2,y)$ but I do not think this is efficient way to solve it.

Comment: Well, now when I posted it I see that 2-dimensional spherical substituion works. I got $2/3$. Someone may check it.

Comment: I got $2/3$ as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. Polar coordinates are the way to go with this integral. A general hint: Whenever you see something of the form: $x^2 +y^2$, immediately think about polar coordinates.

The answer is $\frac{2}{3}$, as you calculated correctly. Well done!